# Why a subscription to an observable work in one place but doesn’t in another?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have several components at work here; `App`, `Column` which contains a list of `Task` components, and `ViewTask` which get displayed when user clicks on a `Task`. I also have a service class that contain my observable.

### UiService Class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UiService {

  constructor() { }

  private taskDisplaySubject = new Subject<any>();
  taskDisplay$ = this.taskDisplaySubject.asObservable();
  showTask(taskData: any) {
    this.taskDisplaySubject.next(taskData);
    console.log(`showTask was called`);
  }

}
```

Here are my `Column` HTML template and its TS

```
<div class="column">
  <header class="column-header">
    <h3 class="column-title">
      {{ columnName }} <span class="num-of-tasks">({{ numOfTasks }})</span>
    </h3>
  </header>

  <div class="tasks-list">
    <app-task
      *ngFor="let task of tasks"
      [task]="task"
      [columnOfTask]="columnName"
      (click)="onTaskClick(task)"
    ></app-task>
  </div>
</div>
```

### ColumnComponent Class

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/services/http.service';
import { UiService } from 'src/app/services/ui.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-column',
  templateUrl: './column.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./column.component.css'],
})
export class ColumnComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpService, private uiService: UiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onTaskClick(taskObject: any) {
    this.uiService.showTask(taskObject);
  }
}
```

Now I have two subscriptions to that observable in two different components: `app` and `view-task`

The problem is the callback function of the subscription in `app` works but the one of the subscription in `view-task` doesn’t. Why is that ? Shouldn’t I see two instances of the task object show up in the console ?

### AppComponent

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { UiService } from './services/ui.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'task-management-frontend';
  @Output() showBoardsModal: boolean = false;
  showDeleteModal: Boolean = false;
  deleteModalType!: string;
  showSidebar = false;
  showTask = false;
  constructor(private uiService: UiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.uiService.taskDisplay$.subscribe((taskData) => {
      this.showTask = true;
      console.log(taskData);
    })

    this.uiService.toggleEmitted$.subscribe(isShown => {
      this.showSidebar = isShown;
    })

  }
```

### ViewTaskComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/services/http.service';
import { UiService } from 'src/app/services/ui.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-task',
  templateUrl: './view-task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-task.component.css'],
})
export class ViewTaskComponent implements OnInit {
  taskId!: string;
  taskTitle!: string;
  taskDescription!: string;
  currentColumn!: string;
  columns!: any[];
  columnId!: string;
  boardId!: string;
  subtasks = [];
  numOfSubtasks!: number;
  numOfSubtasksDone = 0;
  showColumnDropdown: boolean = false;
  showEditDropdown: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpService,
    private ui: UiService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ui.taskDisplay$.subscribe((taskData) => {
      console.log(taskData);
    });

    this.boardId = this.ui.boardId;
   
  }
```

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <aside *ngIf="showSidebar">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </aside>
  <app-titlebar
    (showBoardsModal)="onToggleBoardsModal()"
    (showDeleteModal)="onToggleDeleteModal($event)"
    [displayBoardsModal]="showBoardsModal"
    [ngClass]="{ 'enlarge-titlebar': !showSidebar }"
  ></app-titlebar>
  <div class="main" [ngClass]="{ 'enlarge-main': !showSidebar }">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-view-task *ngIf="showTask"></app-view-task>
  <app-boards-modal
    (hideModalEvent)="onToggleBoardsModal()"
    *ngIf="showBoardsModal"
  ></app-boards-modal>
  <app-delete-modal
    *ngIf="showDeleteModal"
    (hideDeleteModal)="onToggleDeleteModal()"
    [deleteModalType]="deleteModalType"
  ></app-delete-modal>
  <button class="show-sidebar-btn" *ngIf="!showSidebar" (click)="displaySidebar()">
    <svg width="16" height="11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M15.815 4.434A9.055 9.055 0 0 0 8 0 9.055 9.055 0 0 0 .185 4.434a1.333 1.333 0 0 0 0 1.354A9.055 9.055 0 0 0 8 10.222c3.33 0 6.25-1.777 7.815-4.434a1.333 1.333 0 0 0 0-1.354ZM8 8.89A3.776 3.776 0 0 1 4.222 5.11 3.776 3.776 0 0 1 8 1.333a3.776 3.776 0 0 1 3.778 3.778A3.776 3.776 0 0 1 8 8.89Zm2.889-3.778a2.889 2.889 0 1 1-5.438-1.36 1.19 1.19 0 1 0 1.19-1.189H6.64a2.889 2.889 0 0 1 4.25 2.549Z"
        fill="#FFF"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app-view-task` is late in subscribing to the values of subject that is why it's not showing values in `app-view-task`.

As a workaround you can use `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UiService {
  constructor() {}

  private taskDisplaySubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  taskDisplay$ = this.taskDisplaySubject.asObservable();
  showTask(taskData: any) {
    this.taskDisplaySubject.next(taskData);
    console.log(`showTask was called`);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the significance of '1' as an argument to the `ReplaySubject` constructor ? It seems to be working without it.

Comment: If you provide refCount to 1 means it will emit of last 1 value.

Comment: Use a BehaviorSubject, that is what they are for.

Comment: We can use BehaviourSubject  as well @AdrianBrand However we need to provide initial value